# Вычислить пример

Tags: c#

Вот сам пример: 
[image: Сам пример]
Помогите, пожалуйста решить этот пример через C#. Вот код:

```cs
int proiz = 1;
for  (int i = 2; i <= 244; i += 2)
{
    for (int j = 245; j >= 3; j -= 2)
    {

        proiz *= j / i;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(proiz);
```

Comment: У вас что-то не получается? Код не работает? Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить?

Answer (score 1):

Вам не нужен второй цикл, ведь знаменатель связан с числителем.

Кроме того, деление в целых числах даст не тот результат, что следует ожидать, поэтому тип результата нужно задать вещественным, и обеспечить вещественное, а не целочисленное деление

```
double proiz = 1.0;
for (int i = 2; i <= 244; i += 2)   
    proiz *= i / (247.0 - i);
Console.WriteLine(proiz);
```

Comment: `i / (247-i)` деление интов, внимательнее

Comment: @aepot А то, что первый множитель double - уже потом выполняется?

Comment: Я поправил. Да, оператор, совмещенный с присваиванием выполняется после вычисления выражения справа от него.

Comment: Также стоит пояснить в ответе, что с интами у автора такое не заработало бы. А том может не понять, что это за `.0` и при чем здесь `double`.